# How can I add notification bubble to Wordpress admin menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, notifications

I want to show some notification in wordpress admin menu for new posts as we can find one when a new plugin update is available black circle comes to the plugin menu with a number in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit the theme's function.php and append these line of codes -

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'notification_bubble_in_admin_menu');

function notification_bubble_in_admin_menu() {
    global $menu;
    $newitem = get_number_of_new_post_by_type('post');
    $menu[11][0] .= $newitem ? "<span class='update-plugins count-1'><span class='update-count'>$newitem </span></span>" : '';
}

function get_number_of_new_post_by_type($type)
{
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}withdraw WHERE wd_status=0;" ) );
}
```